# ReadFrom.NEAREST settings doesn't work correctly

Tags: spring-data-redis, lettuce

## Server & Redis Setup

I setup Redis servers on AWS as shown below.

ap-northeast-1

- 10.0.100.21 redis/master @ap-northeast-1b
- 10.0.100.38 redis/replica#1 @ap-northeast-1c
- 10.0.100.62 redis/replica#2 @ap-northeast-1d

These nodes are in same VPC.
Redis version = 6.0.9

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-100-21 redis-6.0.9]$ uname -a
Linux ip-10-0-100-21.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal 4.14.193-149.317.amzn2.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Sep 3 19:04:44 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-100-21 redis-6.0.9]$
```

## Ping response time

### 10.0.100.21

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-100-21 ~]$ ping -c 3 10.0.100.21
PING 10.0.100.21 (10.0.100.21) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.100.21: icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=0.014 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.100.21: icmp_seq=2 ttl=255 time=0.039 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.100.21: icmp_seq=3 ttl=255 time=0.028 ms

--- 10.0.100.21 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2054ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.014/0.027/0.039/0.010 ms
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-100-21 ~]$ ping -c 3 10.0.100.38
PING 10.0.100.38 (10.0.100.38) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.100.38: icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=2.65 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.100.38: icmp_seq=2 ttl=255 time=2.60 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.100.38: icmp_seq=3 ttl=255 time=2.69 ms

--- 10.0.100.38 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 2.607/2.649/2.691/0.068 ms
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-100-21 ~]$ ping -c 3 10.0.100.62
PING 10.0.100.62 (10.0.100.62) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.100.62: icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=1.97 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.100.62: icmp_seq=2 ttl=255 time=1.85 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.100.62: icmp_seq=3 ttl=255 time=2.01 ms

--- 10.0.100.62 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.857/1.950/2.014/0.067 ms
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-100-21 ~]$
```

### 10.0.100.38

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-100-38 ~]$ ping -c 3 10.0.100.21
PING 10.0.100.21 (10.0.100.21) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.100.21: icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=2.62 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.100.21: icmp_seq=2 ttl=255 time=3.84 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.100.21: icmp_seq=3 ttl=255 time=2.63 ms

--- 10.0.100.21 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 2.621/3.032/3.846/0.577 ms
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-100-38 ~]$ ping -c 3 10.0.100.38
PING 10.0.100.38 (10.0.100.38) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.100.38: icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=0.016 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.100.38: icmp_seq=2 ttl=255 time=0.027 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.100.38: icmp_seq=3 ttl=255 time=0.028 ms

--- 10.0.100.38 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2027ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.016/0.023/0.028/0.007 ms
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-100-38 ~]$ ping -c 3 10.0.100.62
PING 10.0.100.62 (10.0.100.62) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.100.62: icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=1.12 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.100.62: icmp_seq=2 ttl=255 time=1.05 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.100.62: icmp_seq=3 ttl=255 time=1.14 ms

--- 10.0.100.62 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.057/1.106/1.141/0.035 ms
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-100-38 ~]$
```

### 10.0.100.62

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-100-62 ~]$ ping -c 3 10.0.100.21
PING 10.0.100.21 (10.0.100.21) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.100.21: icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=1.95 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.100.21: icmp_seq=2 ttl=255 time=2.01 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.100.21: icmp_seq=3 ttl=255 time=2.00 ms

--- 10.0.100.21 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.954/1.991/2.014/0.045 ms
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-100-62 ~]$ ping -c 3 10.0.100.38
PING 10.0.100.38 (10.0.100.38) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.100.38: icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=1.08 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.100.38: icmp_seq=2 ttl=255 time=1.12 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.100.38: icmp_seq=3 ttl=255 time=1.26 ms

--- 10.0.100.38 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.082/1.155/1.260/0.085 ms
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-100-62 ~]$ ping -c 3 10.0.100.62
PING 10.0.100.62 (10.0.100.62) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.100.62: icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=0.014 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.100.62: icmp_seq=2 ttl=255 time=0.029 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.100.62: icmp_seq=3 ttl=255 time=0.026 ms

--- 10.0.100.62 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2030ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.014/0.023/0.029/0.006 ms
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-100-62 ~]$
```

From the above, the nearest nodes to each are:

- Nearest node of 10.0.100.21 is 10.0.100.21.
- Nearest node of 10.0.100.38 is 10.0.100.38.
- Nearest node of 10.0.100.62 is 10.0.100.62.

## Application Setup

### Java

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-100-21 redis-6.0.9]$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.9.1" 2020-11-04 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.9.12.1 (build 11.0.9.1+12-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-11.0.9.12.1 (build 11.0.9.1+12-LTS, mixed mode)
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-100-21 redis-6.0.9]$
```

- Spring boot 2.4.0
- Spring Data Redis 2.4.1
- Lettuce 6.0.1

### RedisConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {
    @Value("${readFrom}")
    private String readFrom;

    @Bean
    public LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        RedisStaticMasterReplicaConfiguration config = new RedisStaticMasterReplicaConfiguration("10.0.100.21", 6379);
        config.addNode("10.0.100.38", 6379);
        config.addNode("10.0.100.62", 6379);
        LettuceClientConfiguration clientConfig = LettuceClientConfiguration.builder()
                .readFrom(ReadFrom.valueOf(readFrom)).build();
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(config, clientConfig);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<?,?> redisTemplate(RedisTemplate<?,?> template) {
        template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory());
        StringRedisSerializer serializer = new StringRedisSerializer();
        JdkSerializationRedisSerializer jdkSerializer = new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer();
        
        template.setKeySerializer(serializer);
        template.setValueSerializer(jdkSerializer);
        template.setHashKeySerializer(serializer);
        template.setHashValueSerializer(jdkSerializer);
        return template;
    }
}
```

### SampleRunner.java

```
@Component
public class SampleRunner implements ApplicationRunner {

    @Autowired
    private RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate;

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Runner - start");
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            redisTemplate.opsForValue().get("key1");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        System.out.println("Runner - end");
    }

}
```

Run the application on the each node.

> java -DreadFrom=nearest -jar redis-readfrom-sample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

## Result

### Run the application on 10.0.100.21

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-100-62 redis-6.0.9]$ src/redis-cli monitor | grep GET
1605364234.819490 [0 10.0.100.21:57060] "GET" "key1"
1605364235.825171 [0 10.0.100.21:57060] "GET" "key1"
1605364236.829514 [0 10.0.100.21:57060] "GET" "key1"
1605364237.832915 [0 10.0.100.21:57060] "GET" "key1"
1605364238.836488 [0 10.0.100.21:57060] "GET" "key1"
1605364239.839737 [0 10.0.100.21:57060] "GET" "key1"
1605364240.843086 [0 10.0.100.21:57060] "GET" "key1"
1605364241.847348 [0 10.0.100.21:57060] "GET" "key1"
1605364242.850784 [0 10.0.100.21:57060] "GET" "key1"
1605364243.858162 [0 10.0.100.21:57060] "GET" "key1"
```

**=> NG: Get commands should be sent to nearest node(10.0.100.21),
but sent to far node(10.0.100.62).**

### Run the application on 10.0.100.38

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-100-38 redis-6.0.9]$ src/redis-cli monitor | grep GET
1605364312.650791 [0 10.0.100.38:50216] "GET" "key1"
1605364313.655526 [0 10.0.100.38:50216] "GET" "key1"
1605364314.657089 [0 10.0.100.38:50216] "GET" "key1"
1605364315.659734 [0 10.0.100.38:50216] "GET" "key1"
1605364316.662639 [0 10.0.100.38:50216] "GET" "key1"
1605364317.664621 [0 10.0.100.38:50216] "GET" "key1"
1605364318.666050 [0 10.0.100.38:50216] "GET" "key1"
1605364319.668037 [0 10.0.100.38:50216] "GET" "key1"
1605364320.669549 [0 10.0.100.38:50216] "GET" "key1"
1605364321.671699 [0 10.0.100.38:50216] "GET" "key1"
```

=> OK

### Run the application on 10.0.100.62

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-100-62 redis-6.0.9]$ src/redis-cli monitor | grep GET
1605364353.037076 [0 10.0.100.62:48454] "GET" "key1"
1605364354.041437 [0 10.0.100.62:48454] "GET" "key1"
1605364355.044409 [0 10.0.100.62:48454] "GET" "key1"
1605364356.047743 [0 10.0.100.62:48454] "GET" "key1"
1605364357.050808 [0 10.0.100.62:48454] "GET" "key1"
1605364358.053005 [0 10.0.100.62:48454] "GET" "key1"
1605364359.054525 [0 10.0.100.62:48454] "GET" "key1"
1605364360.056585 [0 10.0.100.62:48454] "GET" "key1"
1605364361.058127 [0 10.0.100.62:48454] "GET" "key1"
1605364362.060059 [0 10.0.100.62:48454] "GET" "key1"
```

=> OK

Do I need any additional settings?

Comment: I found a description below.

> NEAREST Read from any node of the cluster with the lowest latency.

> The latency of the nodes is determined upon the cluster topology refresh. If the topology view is never refreshed, values from the initial cluster nodes read are used.

Is ReadFrom.NEAREST valid only in a cluster configuration?
Can't it be used in master replica configuration or sentinel configuration?

Comment: I checked the Lettuce source code and confirmed that the ReadFrom.NEAREST option is only valid in a cluster configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conclusion: ReadFrom.NEAREST is only valid in cluster configurations. Not valid in Sentinel or Master-Replica configurations.